# How to idiomatically set the version number in a CMAKE/CPACK project?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to edit the CPack settings so that the outputted package file has the correct version number in it.  But that's not all.  I'd like CMake/CPack to have all the places where the version number is updated also be set. The .so file should also be set.  And whatever else needs it.

From where I sit, the [CPack documentation appears to be telling us](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Packaging_With_CPack) to repeat ourselves.

If I do nothing, the output file is like so:

```
mystuff-0.1.1-Linux.tar.gz
```

Let's say the version number should be 1.2.3.

I would think that this is the minimalistic CPACK settings to cause all the version numbers to be changed -- and I placed these lines in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "My app is great")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "My Name")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/README.md")
SET(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/LICENSE")

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "3")
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "2")
```

When I build, the output file is still `mystuff-0.1.1-Linux.tar.gz`

If I repeat myself and do this:

```
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")
```

Now that variable is set, but the file is still `mystuff-0.1.1-Linux.tar.gz`

It seems that I must also change `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME`

What other places do I have to re-state the version number?

This doesn't feel idiomatic. I must be missing something to make this automatic.  Am I supposed to specify the variable at an earlier point in time?  I also see some projects on the internet containing a CPackConfig.cmake file -- the file contains overrides, but I still see some repeating oneself going on in those as well.

[This bug](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=15516) also mentions the same thing.  Apparently, they do want us to repeat ourselves. (as of 2015)  However, even if that is the case, I was wondering if anyone has found a work-around?

If no work around, how about a way to re-state all the variables so that they end up automatically set correctly?  For instance, doing the following is a way to compose the version number by using the variables

```
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")
```

[According to the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPack.html), the file name is composed like this:

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME}")

There are probably other variables that need re-setting.  If I have to restate everything, then exactly what do I need to restate to be complete?

Comment: Please remove the update from your question and post it as an answer. Then, when it becomes possible, accept your answer. Then other will see that your question is answered.

Comment: I'll rephrase it.

Comment: I do not see the _Using CPack with CMake_ part of the documentation telling us to repeat ourselves. Only the _without CMake_ part, but it is not relevant here. Also, I understand that the bug report is not a bug, but that the reporter of the bug misunderstood when CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME is implicitly set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have the following line **after** setting the CPACK_... variables:

```
include (CPack)
```

This is the spot where `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` and others are automatically set, so the version variables (such as `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR`) must be already set at this point.

Comment: This works, though I would prefer a solution that is a bit more idiomatic. (maybe picking up the version number from the `PROJECT(myapp VERSION 1.2.3.4)` field.  I'm marking this as the answer because it works.  Thanks!!

Comment: @010110110101 This is how I do it, I call ```project(myapp VERSION 1.2.3.4)``` then ```include(CPack)``` at the end, no manuall setting of version numbers. it does appear to not have a spot for ```.4``` though :/

Answer (score 4):

If you set your project's version via https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html, you can set the cpack version like

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH ${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH})
include(CPack)
```

Comment: This looks correct but its not working for me on Linux w/ cmake version 3.17.

I had to use this:  
`set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}")`

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look at the documentation for the `PROJECT()` command, which has a `VERSION` field. I'm not sure if it is wired through to CPack, but at least that is the idiomatic place for setting the project version.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/project.html

Comment: I just tried it, though it didn't affect the CPack variables, that does seem to be the idomatic spot.  In order to complete this, I still need to figure out how to recalculate those CPack_* variables.

Comment: According to linked doc, VERSION means _compiler_ version, not project.

Comment: No, it's project version, even though it's not clarified in the linked doc.